# Find $n$ such that $(\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z})^\times \simeq \mathbb{Z}_2 \times \mathbb{Z}_2$.

Tags: group-theory, number-theory

In the ring $(\mathbb{Z}_n, +, \times)$, we know that only $\phi(n)$ of the elements have multiplicative inverses which form the multiplicative group $\mathbb{Z}_n^\times$.  However, since $\phi(n)$ is composite, we don't know which Abelian group this is.

Can we find all $n$ such that this group is $\mathbb{Z}_2 \times \mathbb{Z}_2$?  Not to be confused with $\mathbb{Z}_4$.

---

Notice that $n=5$ does not work, $\mathbb{Z}_5^\times = \mathbb{Z}_4$ while $n=8$ *does* $\mathbb{Z}_8^\times = \mathbb{Z}_2 \times \mathbb{Z}_2$.  Even though $\phi(8) = 2^2(2-1) = 4$ and $\phi(5) = 5-1 = 4$, so **both groups have the same order**.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint:** if $n = \prod p^{\alpha_p}$ then $\phi(n) = \prod p^{\alpha_p-1}(p-1)$ is the order of $(\Bbb Z / n\Bbb Z )^\times$

Comment: With help from [OEIS](https://oeis.org/A000010/b000010.txt), I learned there are only $4$ possible values of $n$.

Comment: @johnmangual do you really need this list??

Comment: The list is telling me that there are probably only finitely many $n$ such that $\phi(n) = m$, so maybe I should ask a different question about these abelian groups.